# mod_deflate not compressing js in wordpress site

Tags: javascript, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-deflate

I'm working on a wordpress site. I enabled mod_deflate with this command in .htaccess:

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css    
application/x-javascript application/javascript
```

but if i test with GTMetrix: http://gtmetrix.com/reports/watchesstock.eu/wd4jvMpZ

it gives me this advice:

> Enable gzip compression "Compressing the following resources with gzip
>   could reduce their transfer size by 229.8KiB (68% reduction)."

and then a list of .js files

Could anyone help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the page, in Chrome's Network tab, it looks like it's being served with type `text/javascript`.  Try adding that to your filter.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Hobo seems like it should work, but it doesn't for me.  I suspect it's because of the version strings on the end of the .js URLs.

I ended up adding:

```
<Files ~ "\.(htm|html|css|js|php)$">
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</Files>
```

This does work for me.

Comment: @sphanley When i marked the answer it was the first version, please look at history. Now it's looking fine.